# Orchard CMS - Count specified items of a container part

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hql, orchardcms

I have 'Association' content type with added Container Part. I also have "Company" and "Bearer" content types which have Containable Part. So Association contains some companies and bearers. I have query which returns me all associations. I'm trying to show items in grid (i have created custom layout provider and custom view for cell of grid). It's working, but when i'm trying to get items from Container part for each associatian - i don't get it. I mean i can get Container Part and even can get Items count , but can't get content items for companies and bearers. Also it will show me whole count of items in Container part. I need to get count of companies in Container part, exclude bearers count. How can i do it? Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you share code

Answer (score 0):

The actual content items aren't stored on ContainerPart. Instead, each contained item's CommonPart has a Container value that links to the container. You need to use LINQ to locate all ContentItems that have CommonPart.Container equal to your container.

```
int containerId = containerItem.Id;

var containedList = _contentManager
                .Query<CommonPart>()
                .Join<CommonPartRecord>()
                .Where(x => x.Container.Id == containerId)
                .List();
```